# Opening an old version of a C file

Tags: c, tipsy

I need to install a program (tipsy) that is used to visualize galaxies simulation (my physics professor recommended it to me and he is using it too).

I tried to install it, I created the makefile but when I run it I get an error for the following piece of code:

```
framepoints(job)

char job[MAXCOMM] ;
{
    char command[MAXCOMM] ;
    char file_root[MAXCOMM] ;
    char particle_type[MAXCOMM] ;

    int box ;

    struct gas_particle *gp ;
    struct dark_particle *dp ;
    struct star_particle *sp ;

    double part_pos[2] ;
    int i,j,k ;

    char projection_type[MAXCOMM] ;

    if (sscanf(job,"%s %d %s %s",command,&box,
        particle_type,file_root) == 4) { 

       if(strcmp(particle_type,"star") != 0 &&
          strcmp(particle_type,"gas") != 0 &&
          strcmp(particle_type,"dark") != 0 &&
          strcmp(particle_type,"gasandstar") != 0 &&
          strcmp(particle_type,"darkandstar") != 0 &&
          strcmp(particle_type,"darkandgas") != 0 &&
          strcmp(particle_type,"all") != 0) {

              printf("<sorry, %s is not a particle option, %s>\n",
                     particle_type,title) ;
              return ;
}
```

The error says:

> non-void function 'framepoints' should return a value

I understood that this return without any value is from versions before C89 but I don't know how to solve it. The code I need to run in order to install it is long so I can't modify it by hand (and also my professor told me it is working).

Comment: Use the C compiler instead. The error message suggests that you're trying to compile C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: enhzflep I am new to this, so after the make file is created, doesn't it include what should be used to compile the code? I mean I just type make in terminal. ( U mean I should do some modifications in the makefile?) Thank you

Comment: This first two lines of this example make almost no sense. The first is I presume declaring a function that takes an int and returns an int using the old style implicit int types. But the second line seems to be declaring a variable before the function body even begins. However the issue in question seems to be that the function should return an int in accordance with the implicit declaration and is returning nothing. Whatever your take this doesnt look like well formed C

Comment: @enhzflep Some newer C compilers like clang also reject this code.

Comment: @Silviutz What compiler are you compiling with?

Comment: @Vality That's a K&R declaration. Perfectly valid, just a bit older.

Comment: @FUZxxl I use terminal on mac, and the code is written in XCode, i am not sure if this is what u were asking for

Comment: @Silviutz - I haven't got the slightest idea how you've created the makefile, much less whether you should fix that process or fix the resultant makefile.

Comment: @enhzflep So I have a folder with many C files, and a configure executable. I run the executable in terminal using ./configure and the makefile was created. Then I tried to run the makefile in terminal and I got this error

Comment: @Vality It makes sense. It's declaring a function that takes a parameter named `job`, and then defines `job` underneath as a `char` array. This is how C used to be. You would define the types of the parameters separately from the function declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
return;
```

to

```
return 0;
```

or something like that to fix this problem. Optionally, pass the option

```
-Wno-return-type
```

to the compiler (if you are using `clang`, the default compiler on OS X) to make this not an error.

Comment: I was thinking to do this, but there are many C files that I need to run, so I should modify it in every single one. I was looking for a faster way if possible.

Comment: So I should add this to the makefile or run it in terminal?

Comment: @Silviutz Yes. Add it to the Makefile. If you show us the makefile, I can tell you where exactly to put this option.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! But now I get another error:                          ld: library not found for -lXaw
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1                                 Wait, let me add the makefile

Comment: Sorry, how can I upload the makefile? It is too big to paste it here?

Comment: @Silviutz Put it in a paste bin. Anyway, the `-lXaw` problem is a different one. Please ask a separate question for it.